# angular find duplicate values of array of objects from response?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Group array of objects from response.

```
[
  { name: ramesh, age: 12, city: mumbai },
  { name: ramesh, age: 12, city: mumbai },
  { name: amit, age: 13, city: mumbai },
  { name: amit, age: 13, city: mumbai },
  { name: ganesh, age: 14, city: mumbai },
  { name: ganesh, age: 14, city: mumbai },
  { name: ganesh, age: 14, city: mumbai },
  { name: ganesh, age: 14, city: mumbai },
];
```

I want to group like this.

```
[
  { name: ramesh, age: 12, city: mumbai },
  { name: "", age: "", city: mumbai },
  { name: amit, age: 13, city: mumbai },
  { name: "", age: "", city: mumbai },
  { name: ganesh, age: 14, city: mumbai },
  { name: "", age: "", city: mumbai },
  { name: "", age: "", city: mumbai },
  { name: "", age: "", city: mumbai },
];
```

I tried with filter, reduce functions in Angular

need to find duplicate value and first value of duplicate will show exact and other duplicates value will convert in empty string

Comment: Why are your strings missing quotes? `"ramesh"` `"mumbai"` etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the `reduce` method of arrays to create a new array of objects with the grouped data

```js
const arr = [
  {name: 'ramesh', age: 12, city: 'mumbai'},
  {name: 'ramesh', age: 12, city: 'mumbai'},
  {name: 'amit', age: 13, city: 'mumbai'},
  {name: 'amit', age: 13, city: 'mumbai'},
  {name: 'ganesh', age: 14, city: 'mumbai'},
  {name: 'ganesh', age: 14, city: 'mumbai'},
  {name: 'ganesh', age: 14, city: 'mumbai'},
  {name: 'ganesh', age: 14, city: 'mumbai'}
];

const groupedArray = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const existingObj = acc.find(obj => obj.name === curr.name && obj.age === curr.age && obj.city === curr.city);
  if (existingObj) {
    acc.push({name: '', age: '', city: curr.city});
  } else {
    acc.push(curr);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(groupedArray);
```

Comment: Can't you replace `obj.name === curr.name && ...` with just `obj == curr`? (double equals, value comparison)